# Unhandled Runtime Error: Should have a queue. This is likely a bug in React. Please file an issue

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, use-state, react-datepicker

[image: Error]

> I'm facing this error after integrating `react-datepicker` in my
> `Next.js` app. Couldn't be able to fix.

*Below some code of my app files:*

**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0",
    "i18next": "^20.2.2",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.1",
    "next": "10.2.0",
    "react": "16.14.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.2.2",
    "react-dom": "16.14.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.2",
    "react-i18next": "^11.8.15",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-redux-toastr": "^7.6.5",
    "reactstrap": "^8.9.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "simple-react-validator": "^1.6.0"
  }
```

**_app.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
import '../styles/globals.css';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store';
import Header from '../components/Layouts/Header';
import Footer from '../components/Layouts/Footer';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Header />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <Footer />
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

**/pages/services/insurance/apply/[type].jsx**

```
/* eslint-disable no-case-declarations */
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Router, { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { Container } from 'reactstrap';
import styles from '../../../../styles/Service.module.css';
import Motor from './forms/motor';
import Travel from './forms/travel';
import routes from '../../../../utils/routes';

const Apply = () => {
  const [type, setType] = useState(null);
  const [form, setForm] = useState(null);
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.query.type) {
      switch (router.query.type) {
        case 'motor':
          setType(router.query.type);
          setForm(Motor);
          break;
        case 'travel':
          setType(router.query.type);
          setForm(Travel);
          break;
        default:
          Router.push(routes.NOT_FOUND);
      }
    }
  }, [router.query]);

  return (
    <Container className={styles.mk_main_container}>
      <div className={styles.mk_service_container}>
        {form}
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Apply;
```

**travel.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import styles from '../../../../../styles/Service.module.css';
import MKLabel from '../../../../../components/Common/Form/Label';
import MKInput from '../../../../../components/Common/Form/Input';
import MKSelect from '../../../../../components/Common/Form/Select';
import MKRadioRounded from '../../../../../components/Common/Form/RadioRounded';
import MKButton from '../../../../../components/Common/Button';
import formStyles from '../../../../../styles/Form.module.css';
import { generateArrayOfYears, generateArrayOfMonths, generateArrayOfDays } from '../../../../../utils/helpers';

const Travel = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <form>
       ...

        <div className="pt-4">
          <MKLabel text="Date of birth?" required />
          <DatePicker
            selected={startDate}
            onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
            isClearable
            placeholderText="I have been cleared!"
          />
        </div>

        ...
    </form>
  );
};

export default Travel;
```

**Directory structure** [image: Directory structure]

---

***What could be the reason and how can be fixed?***

Comment: How are you using the `Travel` component? You're probably not calling it with JSX / createElement properly.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: Everything was fine before integrating `react-datepicker`. I mean if i comment-in `react-datepicker` related code it works.

Comment: How are you using the `Travel` component?

Comment: The way of Next.js page rendering based on routing.

Comment: Updated my answer by adding `[type].jsx` which is basically used as a parent to render child depending on route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be rendering the component object you store in state in `Apply`, not just using it as a variable.

```
const Apply = () => {
  const [type, setType] = useState(null);
  const [form, setForm] = useState(null);
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    // ... elided ...
  }, [router.query]);
  
  // Naming this in PascalCase is important 
  // so React considers it a component
  const FormComponent = form;  

  // Early-out when nothing to render.
  if (!FormComponent) return null;

  return (
    <Container className={styles.mk_main_container}>
      <div className={styles.mk_service_container}>
        <FormComponent />
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

To make things simpler, though, those don't even need to be state atoms:

```
const Apply = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const type = router.query.type;
  const FormComponent = null;
  if (type === "motor") FormComponent = Motor;
  if (type === "travel") FormComponent = Travel;
  if (!FormComponent) return null;
  return (
    <Container className={styles.mk_main_container}>
      <div className={styles.mk_service_container}>
        <FormComponent />
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: null.` I have tried the way you described.

Comment: @RashedRahat See my edit. You're seeing that error because the component is null for a moment due to your useEffect.